# Auto publish graph API on user's Facebook wall

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to implement auto_publish in my app. On clicking the login button, 'publish_stream' permission is requested.

I can seem to get it to publish on the user's wall automatically upon successful login. Here's my code:

```
            function graphStreamPublish(){
            showLoader(true);
            FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', publish, 
                { 
                    message     : "Merry Christmas!",
                    link        : 'http://domain.com',
                    picture     : 'http://domain.com/xxxx.jpg',
                    name        : 'Happy Christmas',
                    description : 'Send a Christmas greeting!'

            }, 
            function(response) {

               console.log(response);
               alert('Shared!');

            });
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(response)` in your callback?

Comment: @AhmedNuaman added console.log(response) but still to no avail :(

Comment: What does it return? It should give you a status message as to what's happening.

Comment: @AhmedNuaman i don't think it returns anything..

Answer (score 0):

Where is your FB.login??

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       //YOU CAN PUT YOUR POSTING CODE HERE
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }, {scope: 'email'});
```

Comment: I already have that chunk in my code, I just did not display it. Note that I have the 'publish_stream' permission request upon login.